# How to pass parameters in a class file to different packages?

Tags: packages, babel, documentclass-writing, parameters

I'm writing a new class file that is based on `book`, and thought of making it available both in an English and in a Dutch version. Easiest to do seemed passing the arguments, so I constructed following class file :

```
...
\ProvidesClass{UGentCourse}[2011/07/28 v1.0 UGentCourse]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions \relax
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\RequirePackage{babel} %francais, polish, spanish, ...
...
```

Which I believed would allow me to do :

```
\documentclass[dutch]{UGentCourse}
```

Strange thing, it doesn't work completely. If I switch it from dutch to English (or back), I get an error :

```
Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option english (dutch) yet.
```

If I rerun the file, the error is gone. I have a faint idea about what is going on, but not really a clue of how I can prevent this from happening. All help appreciated.

Comment: It's normal; **babel** writes the language in the `.aux` file. If you change from Dutch to English, at the subsequent compilation LaTeX finds the annotation about Dutch and doesn't know about the language.

Comment: I realized. I just need a way to get rid of that. Which @mhp gave me, thanks for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can avoid this error by modifying your class definition as follows:

```
\ProvidesClass{UGentCourse}[2011/07/28 v1.0 UGentCourse]

\DeclareOption{english}{\AtEndOfClass{\main@language{english}}}
\DeclareOption{dutch}{\AtEndOfClass{\main@language{dutch}}}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\RequirePackage[dutch, english]{babel}
```

The last language in the option list passed to the `babel` package (i.e. `english` here) is the default language. It is active at the beginning of the document if no language has been specified in the optional argument of `\documentclass.`

Comment: Thx, this works smoothly.